# WordPress theme development Header Errors

Tags: wordpress, themes

i am making a WordPress theme and i have some problems.Plz help me.

1)how to get header on the pages. I am doing this

```
<?php get_header();?>
```

its work fine on the index page but on others pages its gives error  undefined function get_header()
how to get header proper in wordpress theme is there anything i have to change in the configration files for this.

But if i add header like this

```
<?php include 'header.php';?>
```

Then the bellow problem occur.

2) how to get the site url in header so that i include my css and js files currently i am doing this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo network_site_url() . '/css/style.css' ?>">
```

similarly like header network_site_url() works fine on index page but on other pages it give error of undefined method.

Comment: check , is ther any php condition for home page before get_header(); and to get file path in wordpress use <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/style.css">

Comment: kindly tell me how to add that condition on home page and also tell me how to get header on other pages i use this get_template_directory_uri(); but it give errors on other pages(undefined metrhod)

Comment: get_header() should work on all files of your theme. you might not be using it properly. If you are new to theme development, start off from a blank theme. I would suggest  using underscores.me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "bloginfo('template_url')" instead of  "network_site_url()";

now your link become like :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url') '/css/style.css' ?>">
```

Comment: this work fine on index page but not on other pages it is giving error Call to undefined function bloginfo()
kindly tell me how to get header on other pages is there any configuration is required to get header

Comment: <?php get_header(); ?>

Comment: put css file in header.php and put that on each page starting with add
`<?php get_header();?>`